# Is there a description of the IL disassembler icons available somewhere

Tags: .net, assemblies

I'm playing around with the MS IL disassembler, which lets you view the contents of a .Net assembly. The classes and Interfaces are shown in a tree view, nicely encoded with colors and icons.

It's rather easy to guess the meaning of most icons, e.g. a blue icon with a capital 'I' inscribed is an interface, a grey one with an 'E' in it is an enumeration, but some items -- esp. the ones you get to see when you open an node -- are not always that easy to guess (maybe it's just me). What is the meaning of a light blue diamond with an 'S' in it? Probably a static public member, but I'm unhappy with the word 'probably' here. Similarly, blue class symbols with a white rectangle seem to be generics, but this, again, is only a guess.

Is there an official complete list with explanations/descriptions available somewhere?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Clicking "Help" under "Help" and "Tree View Icons" shows what the icons mean, however it appears to be missing a few. Below is an exhaustive list.

- [image: Metadata] - Metadata, such as the assembly manifest, type declaration modifiers, etc.
- [image: Namespace] - A Namespace.
- [image: Instance Field] - An instance field, assembly, or netmodule.
- [image: Static Field] - A static field.
- [image: Class, Delegate, Module] - A class, delegate, or module (VB.NET).
- [image: Generic Class or Delegate] - A class or delegate with type arguments (generics).
- [image: Struct] - A struct.
- [image: Generic Struct] - A struct with type arguments (generics).
- [image: Interface] - An interface.
- [image: Generic Interface] - An interface with type arguments (generics).
- [image: Enumeration] - An enumeration.
- [image: Instance Method] - An instance method or constructor.
- [image: Generic Instance Method] - An instance method with type arguments (generics).
- [image: Static Method] - A static method or type initializer (static constructor).
- [image: Generic Static Method] - A static method with type arguments (generics).
- [image: Property] - A property, instance or static.
- [image: Event] - An event, instance or static.

Comment: @Thomas There is an "official" list of the icons in ildasm's help (See the edit), though oddly it isn't as complete as this.